# writing CSS for multi-level horizontal menus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I do a lot of work during the day and I program in quite a few languages so doing CSS work is a little tough because i don't specialize in it.  I have run into an issue where wordpress no longer works for me so I have to do mysite on my own.  can you guys point me to a web resource that will show me how to get a a look of a multi-level horiz. menu at the top of my homepage similar to the one found here?

https://www.cssscript.com/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/

I got that link from a similar thread here on S/O.

I copied all of the code there and put it in the appropriate CSS and HTML files, but I do not get the multi-leveledness.  I only got a vertical menu on the left side without color.  I'm a source coder, and generally automate things and I'm horrible at designing anything.  I draw stick people and that's as far as my artistic talent goes.  so CSS falls into that same boat.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really only got a vertical menu on the left side without color, that sounds like none of the CSS styles are actually taking effect. And since none of the elements have classes from what I can see, it sounds like your CSS isn't actually loading or being applied to the DOM. How have you included the CSS rules into your website? Before trying to use a different demo, try to get this specific one working by looking at your HTML structure and figuring out how to get the styles to grab onto the right elements...